# client_side_validations by DavieJones in form validator not parsing correctly Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Im using cliebnt_side_validators.js to form validate on client side

I have the following on my form.erb

```
<%= f.text_field :sale_cost , class: "form-control" ,:required => "true" , :validates =>" numericality: {greater_than: 1 } " %>
```

which results in the folowing HTML view

```
 <input class="form-control" required="required" validates=" numericality: {greater_than: 1 } " type="text" name="order[sale_cost]" id="order_sale_cost" />
```

However it requires its presence but it will accept any value

I'm aware its syntax issue but im going blind trying to see what ive done wrong or to get alternatives to process.

JS available here https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations
my js is v4.2.12 (https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations)

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Im using client_side_validators.js to validate input on forms, its getting the required part ok but not the greater_than:

Comment: Have you tried, `validate: numericality: {greater_than: 1 }`

Comment: Tried that where Lucas ? ive tride :validate and :validates on the form.ERB as well as trying to get it to parse validate: and validates:

Comment: In your code, i see `:validates =>" numericality: {greater_than: 1 } "`, I'm suggesting you try `:validate => numericality: {greater_than: 1 }`

Comment: yeah that dosn't work Lucas. Thanks

Comment: `validate: { numericality: {greater_than: 1 } }`